# How to reliably initialize IPC semaphores?

Tags: concurrency, initialization, posix, semaphore, sysv-ipc

The problem: How to use SysV semaphores for synchronisation between two processes (let’s call them `procA` and `procB`), assuming that both are independently run from the shell (none of them is spawned by the `fork`/`exec` combination) and that the semaphores must be created by one of these two processes.

Quoting `man semget`:

> The values of the semaphores in a newly created set are 
>   indeterminate. (POSIX.1-2001 is explicit on this point.)  Although
>   Linux, like many other implementations, initializes the semaphore
>   values to 0, a portable application cannot rely on this: it
>   should explicitly initialize the semaphores to the desired values.

Assume we would like to write portable code that relies only on POSIX guarantees, but no Linux-specific guarantees. Very well, so it is impossible to atomically create a semaphore set and initialize it. This must be done by two separate calls.

So, the code for creation of the semaphore set for `procA` would look sth like this:

```
int sem_id = semget(key, nsems, IPC_CREAT | S_IRWXU);
```

And same for `procB` – this way, whichever process happens to need the semaphores for the first time, it also creates them; otherwise, it simply obtains the semaphore set’s ID and is ready to use it.

Problems start to appear when initialisation is required. The instruction for initialisation is of course `semctl` with `SETALL` – but: • the initialisation should be done only once, and • the initialisation should be done before the semaphores are used. This could of course be enforced by… semaphores, but such such solution is unfortunately recursive: we need semaphores to set up semaphores, which themselves need semaphores to be set up and so forth.

Is it possible to do this only using sysV semaphores, or am I right in my assumption that I have to resort to other IPC facilities like signals or message queues to be able to reliably set up these semaphores?

Comment: A little later in `man semget` it says: *"Initialization can be done using semctl(2) SETVAL or SETALL operation.  Where multiple peers do not know who will be the first to initialize the set, checking for a nonzero sem_otime  in the associated data structure retrieved by a semctl(2) IPC_STAT operation can be used to avoid races."*

Comment: @Kenney Yep. So we have an `if`. And an `if` still needs some effort to ensure it’s atomic.

Comment: @Kenney I mean, we have to ensure that in between of checking whether or not `sem_otime` is nonzero and initializing the semaphores no other process messes with the same set. And somehow I can’t see how to do this.

Comment: Yes I see your point. It looks broken ;-)

Comment: Maybe specifying `IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL` on `semget` would do the trick: if the semaphore exists, it will return `EEXISTS`. The caller that doesn't get the error does the initialisation, and the one that does get the error does another `semget` without `IPC_CREAT` (and does not initialize it).

Comment: @Kenney That looks nice, but this still doesn’t guarantee that the semaphores are initialized before they are used – unless the process that got `EEXISTS` spins on `sem_otime`. And that’s busy-waiting. Sadly I’m explicitly forbidden to do busy-waiting :(

Answer (score 0):

In my experience this isn't a problem in the real world.  I put the IPC creation and initialization in a separate program that is called by a system startup script in advance of any client program being run.  The IPC resources are never removed, and only go away when the box is rebooted.

If I had to create the resources on the fly, I'd have the creator program start as a separate user and create the resource with owner-only permissions.  It would then initialize it, and finally grant permissions to the client's user, and exit.

The clients would simply retry on ENOENT or EACCES, perhaps with a nanosleep.

On second though, I'd probably just use POSIX semaphores, since sem_open(3) let's you specify O_EXCL and an initial value.  Old Sys V habits are hard to break.